# Move Each Google Sheet tab to a separate spreadsheet and also get the URL of each sheet collected in a different spreadsheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have 50 different tabs in one Google Sheet. Now I want to create a different spreadsheet for each tab with the help of script. This will create 50 different spreadsheets. Better if all the new sheets are created in a different folder in the drive.

Further, after creating new spreadsheet for each tab, I want to get the URL of all new sheets into a different spreadsheet.

I tried to find a solution to this in the Stackoverflow community but could not find a perfect answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Suggestion: Use `create()`, `copyTo()`, and `moveTo()`

You can use the `SpreadsheetApp.create()` to create a new spreadsheet then use `copyTo()` to copy a specific tab, including its formatting, to the new spreadsheet. You can then use `moveTo()` to move the new spreadsheet to a specific folder.

Try this script:

```
function newSheet() {
  var sourceSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheets(); //Gets all the tabs on the source spreadsheet. 
  var destFolder = DriveApp.getFolderById('folder_id'); // Destination folder. Replace folder_id with the folder ID
  var sheetURL = []; //Array to store the URL of the newly created sheets.

  sourceSheet.forEach(sheet => { //Loops through each of the tabs and gets the names of each one
    var name = sheet.getName();
    var newSheet = SpreadsheetApp.create(name); // Creates a new spreadsheet with the same filename as the tab.
    var newSheetURL = newSheet.getUrl(); //Gets the URL of the newly created sheet.

    sheetURL.push([newSheetURL]);
    sheet.copyTo(SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl(newSheetURL)).setName(name); //Copies the tab from the source sheet to the new spreadsheet.
    SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl(newSheetURL).deleteSheet(newSheet.getSheetByName('Sheet1')); //Deletes the default Sheet1 tab.
    DriveApp.getFileById(newSheet.getId()).moveTo(destFolder);//Moves the newly created spreadsheet to the specified folder.
  });

  var destSheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById('sheet_id');
  //Opens the spreadsheet store the URLs to. Replace sheet_id with the ID of the spreadsheet  
  destSheet.getSheetByName('sheet_tab').getRange(1, 1, sheetURL.length).setValues(sheetURL);
  //Inserts the URLs. Replace sheet_tab with the name of the tab to store the URLs on.
}
```

Note that it may take a while for the script to create a new Google Sheets file for each of the 50 tabs that's on your source spreadsheet and that this script has to be [bound](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/bound#or) to the source spreadsheet.

### References:

- [create()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet-app#createname)
- [copyTo()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#copytospreadsheet)
- [moveTo()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/file#movetodestination)

Comment: Thanks for your response. I Tried to use the code but shows and error. Below is the link of both the sheets. URL of the master sheet to be split https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Jsiol2TCUrysItA6FNrUtpxQbi7dEFEux5OPeQhAPbI/edit?pli=1#gid=2071730963 and URL of the Destination sheet where to store the new sheet URL https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/15nnDmtjPYcR8o_q2g93FZhBDL5kArv1DnCNmv09NQR4/edit#gid=0 and the folder id 134viks0PuJsI_EN3JEjTIDchPylE9ZwS

Comment: Thanks for letting me know. I was not encountering any error testing the code on my own sheet. May I know the exact error you're getting?

Comment: @ DuuEyn thanks for very super quick reply... the issue is solved I think there was some mistake from my side in copying the code... Sorry for inconvenience and thank you for the excellent solution.